# \Pause is not working

Tags: beamer, pause

Below is my code of beamer. I'm using pause for the first time, it is not working in my document.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}

\title {Coding theory for juniors}

\author{\textbf{Kaustubh Limaye}}

\institute{\large {\textbf{Roots Camp, RAM}}}

\date{\today}

\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=FullScreen} 

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{graphs}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{esvect}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usetheme{Pittsburgh}

\usepackage[accumulated]{beamerseminar}

\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}

\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}

\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}

\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}

\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}

%Document Environment 

\useinnertheme[shadow=true]{rounded}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{environ}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

    \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]

    \frametitle{A Childhood Game}
    
    As far a I remember, when I was your age, we used to play one game. That game involves two cans and a string. 
    
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{communication.jpg}
    \end{figure}    
    
    \begin{block}{Question}
        Do you think that the communication is feasible?
    \end{block}
    
    \pause
    
    Whatever bob says, will not be completely understandable to eve due to $\textbf{Noise}$. Still Eve can somehow manage to figure out what bob said. 
    
    \pause
    
    So, whatever Bob says goes through a noisy channel and Eve receives a message with noise (error) and she corrects it.  \pause
    Suppose. 
    \end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Please help me out with this. The document is not showing anything written after first pause.

Thank you!

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you don't need `\usepackage{graphicx}`, `\usepackage{color}`, `\usepackage{amsthm}`, `\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}`, `\usepackage{etoolbox}`, beamer loads all of them for you.
If your tex distribution is up-to-date, you don't need `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` either, that's the default. Instead of `\textbf{Kaustubh Limaye}` you should use `\setbeamerfont{author}{series=\bfseries}` and instead of `\large {\textbf{Roots Camp, RAM}}`, use `\setbeamerfont{title}{series=\bfseries,size=\large}`.

Comment: The `\centering` in figures is unnecessary, beamer automatically centres them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no access to your figure. However, the problem here is frame option `allowframebreaks`. If you remove that it works flawlessly.

Option `allowframebreaks` should only be used for commands that generate more than a frame-full of output, i.e. bibliography.

Comment: But I would need frame breaks. Is there any other way to use \pause? Or any other command except \pause.

Comment: Why do you need frame breaks? There is probably a better way of achieving what you are trying to do.

Comment: @KaustubhLimaye Overlays and framebreaks don't work well together. Don't try to combine them. You can use overlays to split your frame into multiple slides. It is really not necessary to use framebreaks on frames you create yourself.

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much for your help.